# Error compiling PDF using RStudio/knitr with a plot

Tags: r, pdf, plot, rstudio, knitr

Posted this on RStudio help already but seeing if anybody here has any idea. I'm getting the following error below when I try to Knit PDF with a plot in the document using RStudio. The error does not occur when I try to Knit PDF without a plot nor does it occur when I Knit HTML with the plot. I'm on a Mac with Yosemite.

```
sh: line 1: 3234 Trace/BPT trap: 5 gs -dSAFER -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -c save pop -f fcmb_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf 2>&1 > /dev/null
!!! Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 133!
output file: fcmb.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
l.98 \begin{center}\includegraphics

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

Edit: It seems like the culprit was that the graphicx package wasn't being added for some reason. I hacked a solution by just including

header-includes: \usepackage{graphicx}

in the front-matter of my document.

Comment: Could you include your code please?

Comment: Not sure what code I can provide that would be helpful. I'm using RStudio and using the Knit HTML or Knit PDF options. Knit PDF is successful until I the plot (added the code to my post). But it's most likely not the plot or the R code itself that is the problem since it works with Knit HTML.

Comment: Just put your entire `.Rmd` file in your question, not only the section which produces the error.

Comment: Please include the code (minimal working example) that produces the error and consider answering the question yourself. Someone in the future (hello) might get a similar error and it would be neat to have a solution at hand.

Comment: hello, I'm someone in the future

Answer (score 2):

I also get the error **"sh: line 1:  Trace/BPT trap: 5 gs -dSAFER -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -c save pop -f .pdf 2>&1 > /dev/null !!! Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 133!"**
when I use the command "pdfcrop" on a mac with Yosemite. This is because Ghostscript is broken on Yosemite: https://tug.org/mactex/yosemite.html. So you might need to install the Ghostscript 9.15 package.

Comment: Please add tags to make sure that your question will reach to the target audience.

Comment: I seemed to fix this using `brew install ghostscipt; brew link --overwrite ghostscript`